# I create getfeatureinfo with popup but it dosn't work (error 404)

Tags: openlayers-2, error, popup, getfeatureinfo, mapproxy

This is my code for my page (index.html)

```
            info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
            title: 'get feature info',
            queryVisible: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function (event) {
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken",
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        event.text,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));
                }
            }
        });

        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();
```

and it's proxy code :  OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

But I see a 404 error. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you have a proxy.cgi file? and have the domains that you use for the wms been added to this?

Comment: No i dont have a proxy.cgi file, should I? and i haven't apache server is it a problem ?

Comment: Yes - you will need a proxy.cgi file for a Proxy if you are using apache as the web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache as the web server, you can use a proxy file called proxy.cgi to get round the problem of [cross-origin javascript security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The following is taken from [OpenLayers FAQs about the ProxyHost setting](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhydoIneedaProxyHost)

> **Why do I need a ProxyHost?**
>
> Due to security restrictions in Javascript, it is not possible to
>   retrieve information from remote domains via an XMLHttpRequest.
>
> Classes like WFS and GeoRSS use XMLHTTPRequest to get their data. If
>   they are querying a remote server (anything other than the machine
>   hosting your page), you must install a proxy script somewhere web
>   accessible on that machine. See below for how to set up your own
>   ProxyHost.
>
> If the OpenLayers.ProxyHost variable is not set to a valid proxy host,
>   requests are sent directly to the remote servers. In most cases, the
>   result will be a security exception, although this exception often
>   occurs silently. How do I set up a ProxyHost?
>
> An example proxy host script is available here:
>   trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi
>
> For the standard Apache configuration, you would place proxy.cgi into
>   your /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory.
>
> Once a proxy host script has been installed, you must then edit the
>   OpenLayers.ProxyHost variable to match that URL.
>
> Given the above standard Apache configuration:
>
> ```
> OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
> ```
>
> If you have done something like this, you should be able to visit:
>
> ```
>  http://YourDomain.example.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi
> ```
>
> The resulting content at that page should be the openlayers.org
>   website.
>
> If you get a 404 error instead, either the proxy script is not in the
>   right location, or your webserver is not configured correctly.

[A sample proxy.cgi file can be found here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi)

If you are using something like tomcat/jetty for your web server, then you will probably use a jsp for the proxy file, an [example proxy.jsp file can be found here](http://snipplr.com/view/17987/jsp-proxy-for-javascript-applications)

Comment: I'm trying to query feature info on geoserver WMS . I refered this openlayers example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html

Comment: In that example the GetFeatureInfo url is http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms whereas the web page is at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html. Therefore they need to go through a proxy (server side) to avoid a 404